# iOS: Notify other tabbed view controllers about a change in its dataset

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller and inside it two controllers: a mapview controller and a tableview + NSFetcheddata controller. Both display info about a specific day from core data and have a button to display a day selector modally.

I have achieved having my controllers dataset changing when their modal view controller disappears through delegation but I would like the two controllers to update their data and not only the one who displayed the modal controller.

I thought about creating a protocol in both controllers and setting each other as its delegate but I would like to know if I'm doing right here.

Cheers,

Thierry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tons of different ways to do this. One way is to use NSNotificationCenter. Define your own custom notification name:

```
static NSString *const CSDataUpdatedNotification = @"CSDataUpdatedNotification";
```

Subscribe to this notification in both of your controllers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataUpdated:) name:CSDataUpdatedNotification object:nil];
```

And implement `dataUpdated:` to update your data:

```
- (void)dataUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Handle updates here
}
```

In the controller causing the change, post the notification:

```
- (void)updateData
{
    // Data updating routine
    // ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CSDataUpdatedNotification object:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Seems a proper way to handle this. It didn't really feel right to call a delegate's method from a delegate's method like I was doing so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could set both as the delegate (i.e. two delegates) and re-use your modal view controller for both.

Alternatively, use NSNotificationCenter, <del>but I think the delegate method is better, because the relationship is closer this way</del>. which is the way to go if you want to message more than one object.

Comment: The delegate pattern is really only designed for 1-to-1 relationships. NSNotifications are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Used Cameron's example for using notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Thierry, 
being new to iOS, I wouldn't call this an "answer", but using a global notification system does not sound right for this kind of problem to me.

Looking for an answer to a similar problem, I stumbled over references to  NSFetchedResultsController, which will calculate results for you, readily to be used as a UITableView model - only reading knowledge. The part relevant to your problem seems to be its delegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, which defines a few methods which will allow to communicate changes to the result to any number of interested parties.

But as I said, I just stumbled over it, and are just now trying to make use of it.

Regards, nobi